# Java Optional.ifPresentOrElse with return value

Tags: java, null, option-type, nullable

In Java, I have recently began to adopt the `Optional` type more in my code. This allows for better `null`-value handling and to some extend also safer code. `Optional` has the `ifPresentOrElse` method which allows you to perform a specific action for when a value is present, or a specific action for when no value is present. However, this method does not allow you to declare a return type.

Is there an easy way I can use optionals and a `ifPresentOrElse`-like method to return values while unwrapping an `Optional`?

Comment: To get return value, replace `opt.ifPresentOrElse(a, b)` with `r = opt.map(a).orElseGet(b)`

Comment: @Andreas Just to note: That inolves converting `a` from a `Consumer` to a `Function` and `b` from a `Runnable` to a `Supplier`.

Comment: @Slaw That would be a requirement of the goal to *return* a value, regardless of how they are used, i.e. it's not really the use of `map` or `orElseGet` that makes that requirement, it's a prerequisite of what OP wants.

Comment: @Andreas Makes sense. I understood the question as wanting to perform actions on the `Optional` while unwrapping the _original_ value (whether it was present or not). Sort of like `also` in Kotlin. Your solution, while still capable of doing that, doesn't read the same. However, after seeing [the OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60839319/6395627) I see they were after what you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, subclassing `Optional` is impossible as all of it's initializers are `private`. So any solution would have to come for a class or type that is not a subclass of `Optional`. The convenience method + interfaces below provides the desired behavior.

```
public interface Consumer<InputType, OutputType> {
    public OutputType consume(InputType inputType);
}

public interface Runnable<OutputType> {
    public OutputType run();
}

public static <ReturnType, OptionalType> ReturnType ifPresentOrElse(Optional<OptionalType> optional, Consumer<OptionalType, ReturnType> consumer, Runnable<ReturnType> runnable) {
    return optional.isPresent() ? consumer.consume(optional.get()) : runnable.run();
}
```

Comment: @Tomáš Záluský 's solution is a good compromise without adding boiler plate code.

Comment: @IceMan The solution by Tomáš would fail to compile.

Comment: Creating custom interfaces here is unnecessary. Your `Consumer` interface is effectively a `Function` and your `Runnable` interface is effectively a `Supplier`. With that in mind, you can use [Andreas' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839318/java-optional-ifpresentorelse-with-return-value#comment107640929_60839318) which doesn't involve creating a utility method. Note that the answer by Tomáš is effectively the same solution as that suggested by Andreas except Tomáš uses the wrong types.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming following declarations *(EDIT: note `Consumer` and `Runnable` are interfaces from @ImJustACowLol's self-answer, not `java.util` interfaces. For case the self-answer were deleted, the interfaces are same as those in `java.util` except the functional interface method has generic return type instead of `void`. Anyway the naming should have been chosen differently.)*:

```
Consumer<InputType, OutputType> yourConsumer = ...;
Runnable<OutputType> yourRunnable = ...;
Optional<InputType> yourOptional = ...;
```

you can compose following statement

```
OutputType result = yourOptional.map(yourConsumer).orElseGet(yourRunnable);
```

which admittedly doesn't fit in single method call, though still is concise and readable enough, IMHO.

Comment: Assuming `java.util.Optional`: (1) The `java.lang.Runnable` interface is not generic; (2) The `map` method expects a `java.util.function.Function`; (3) The `orElseGet` method expects a `java.util.function.Supplier`.

Comment: @Slaw you are true of course, I assumed declarations on types declared in ImJustACowLol's answer. It's both mine and ImJustACowLol's mistake that I built my answer upon another one and s/he chosen such unlucky naming. I will edit answer to warn these types are not `java.util` types.